# include figure, auto-fit image and add caption at same time

Tags: floats, captions, diagrams

I have to include some images to illustrate a problem. So I used the following code to auto-scale them to text-witdh, which works amazing. But how can I add some caption? (I have to label and number all figures)?

I found some solutions with google (caption etc.) but AFAIK they need a figure-object. So I also tried to use it instead of this box, but then I was not able to auto-fit the image.

```
\begin{center}
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pstack}}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\usepackage{capt-of}
...

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pstack}
  \captionof{figure}{foo}\label{bar}
\end{minipage}
```

or

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pstack}
  \caption{foobar}\label{barbaz}
\end{figure}
```

You do not need the `\makebox` if your images are of the same width.

Comment: wow, works like a charm!